# How to reinstall every shared library for a given program?

Tags: macos, library

I am not so knowledgeable on shared libraries and how they work. I am having a complex issue that involves shared libraries, probably because something is missing somewhere. I have tried

```
otool -L my_problematic_library.dylib
```

And it returns a list of other `.dylib` files

I recursively tried `otool -L` on those files, and get even more `.dylib` files.

There are other complexities which are out of scope here, but the upshot is I'd like to reinstall all shared libraries (and the shared libraries used by those shared libraries, recursively), for a given program. In other words, reinstall *all* the shared libraries used by a given program

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give me more context on the actual issue? AFAIK there's no dynamic library repository that I've ever heard of for MacOS that you could download them from to reinstall. Reinstalling the software is probably the best way to restore these to their proper location.

Comment: @ToddDabney sure thing, it's [this](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/356) issue that I'm trying to solve (first reply recommends `otool`)

Comment: @stevec Have you just updated R? - Or have you also updated macOS at the same time?

Comment: @jksoegaard it’s on a work computer so although I made no change to the OS, it is definitely possible something was pushed by admins at work. It’s was and still is Sierra. Another thing I don’t know much about is how some R libraries use shared libraries (.so files, c/c++, dylib, dll). I don’t know enough to understand what may have happened, except to say I did update R libraries and that may have done things to shared libraries

Comment: I would suggest looking at the file permissions on that dylib also. Can you actually open the file and look into its contents using an editor for example? I definitely wouldn't start by reinstalling all shared libraries - rather use otool to figure out which library doesn't exist at all